# How to split column into 3 column in large text file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file which is 1 GB. 
I want to read it and split one column into 3 separate column.

There is one column - COMPONENT_IDS , I need to split it into three new columns- DOC_ID, DOC_TITLE, PROD

example:

```
We have to split COMPONENT_IDS  into 3 columns (DOC_ID, DOC_TITLE, PROD) use ; as seperator. For a "##" seperator, it should come as multiple records
For example INK-MET-100 vs 300;INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose;Invokana##ENC-010864-13;INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014;Invokana

COMPONENT_IDS
INK-MET-100 vs 300;INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose;Invokana
ENC-010864-13;INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014;Invokana

DOC_ID                DOC_TITLE                                     PROD
INK-MET-100 vs 300    INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose   Invokana
ENC-010864-13         INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014          Invokana
```

Comment: `df[['DOC_ID','DOC_TITLE','PROD']]=df['COMPONENT_IDS'].str.split(';',expand=True)` ? basically split on seperator = `;` and expand

Comment: @anky_91 , Thanks for the reply. But file is taking too much time if i read as dataframe. Can you provide alternate solution for this?

Comment: whats your end goal, do you want a dataframe? or do you want a new csv?

Answer (score 0):

Below Python Script might help you. 
You can change the integer value 40 of "format("DOC_ID", 40)" etc. as per your requirement.
Below script is reading your data file and converting it to 3 columns and redirecting it your output file. By using loop here we can avoid the high memory utilization issue.

$ cat test --> Orignal file

COMPONENT_IDS

INK-MET-100 vs 300;INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose;Invokana

ENC-010864-13;INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014;Invokana

$ cat test.py --> Python Script

import pandas as pd

fopen=open('test') # orignal file

fout=open('output','w') # output file

print('{: <{}}'.format("DOC_ID", 40),'{: <{}}'.format("DOC_TITLE", 60),'{: <{}}'.format("PROD", 40),file=fout)

for i in fopen:

```
    if i.startswith('COMPONENT_IDS'):

           continue

    else:

            (DOC_ID, DOC_TITLE, PROD)=tuple(i.strip().split(';'))

            print('{: <{}}'.format(DOC_ID, 40),'{: <{}}'.format(DOC_TITLE, 60),'{: <{}}'.format(PROD, 40),file=fout)
```

---

$ python3 test.py --> script execution

$ cat output

DOC_ID                                   DOC_TITLE                                                    PROD

INK-MET-100 vs 300                       INVOKANA - 100 vs 300 mg as a Starting Dose                  Invokana
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l2Ad.png)
ENC-010864-13                            INVOKANA PI and Med Guide - May 2014                         Invokana